# Fragment placed on top of NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm trying to add a `PreferenceFragment`in my application. The problem is, it's auto placed on top of my `NavigationDrawer`.

```
public class SetPreferenceActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.settings);
  navigationDrawer(); // Loads the NavigationDrawer

  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
               new Settings()).commit();

 }
```

As you can see I load the "SettingsFragment" and replace the content with it? (I'm unsure) but it places it on top of everything else.. Here's my Settings fragment.

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceFragment  {
    static final String TAG = "MAIN";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }
```

Everything work as expected, BUT the PreferenceFragment are loaded in front, covering up the NavigationDrawer slideout, I tried calling `bringToFront();` on the listview, with no luck.

A picture for reference :

[image]

Is it possible to tell the fragment to load behind the listview? I also tought about loading the fragment in a ViewPager, but I get an error that the Pager Adapter wont accept fragments of type PreferenceFragment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't replace `android.R.id.content`, use the the id of the `FrameLayout` you have in the layout that contains your `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Why isn't this on some sort of documentation for the Navigation Drawer on the tutorial page?!? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks adneal. Saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what adneal said (in case others have the same problem):

The Activity which calls the PreferenceFragment needs to have the `setContentView()` method if you **extend** the Activity with your NavigationDrawer:

```
public class SetPreferenceActivity extends MyNavigationDrawer {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.settings);

  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer_frame_layout,
               new Settings()).commit();    
 }
```

And the `settings.xml` should only contain a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and i resolved it by replacing **android.R.id.content** to **R.id.container**.