# How to create PreferenceFragment associated with a sliding drawer in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer, preferencefragment

My app has a sliding drawer menu,in which i need to load the preferenceFragment in one of the fragment of the sliding menu.I created a code where preferenceFragment is loaded into fragment but when i close the drawer the prefrenceFragment is not disappearing.I can close it only by pressing back button.My complete code and app image is displayed below.Please help me?

**Settings Fragment**

```
public class Settings_fragment extends Fragment
{
public Settings_fragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false); 

    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    return rootView;
}
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_layout);
        }
}
}
```

**NavigationDrawer**

```
public class Homepage_activity extends ActionBarActivity
{
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage_layout);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new Today_rep_fragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Monthly_rep_fragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new Settings_fragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new Waterfacts_fragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new Help_fragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new About_fragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: preferenceFragment is not disappearing while clicking sliding drawer]

Comment: Please share your layout file

Comment: I don't find any problem with the xml.Any way i couldn't share it in comments section.It says too many comments!How can share?Did you notice my code.Setting is the only item that is using preferenceFragment,all other places it's fragment.See the code in the upper section,i'm calling preferenceFrgament inside the fragment.Is there any way to remove the prefrencefragment when drawer is open for another selection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are replacing PreferenceFragment in SettingsFragment's onCreateView why?? According to your code you are replacing SettingsFragment with PreferenceFragment which is static, and not destroying or removing, avoid static member functions, classes and variables in your code, because they have globally available anywhere in your code. Go through your code and edit your question

Comment: Hello harris..actually i want to load a prefernceFragment in one of the fragment associated with the NavigationDrawer.Is there any better solution that the above.Could you tell me how do i remove the settings fragment when the preferenceFragment is replaced?

Comment: @Anish google and study why use preference fragmemts? I couldn't understand what you want to achieve, edit your question and clearly mention your problem, than someone down vote,

Comment: before someone downvotes me..you better take a look at the following links.These are somewhat similar to my situation.I am a newbie in android,so mistakes can happen my friend..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493713/fragment-placed-on-top-of-navigationdrawer

Comment: Add Framelayout in your xml file with id content_frame where you are using navigation drawer and replace fragment using R.id.content_frame rather than android.r.id.content. for understanding your are using android's default content, if you will use your own content_frame than your problem will resolve

Answer (score 0):

First sahre your xml file for navigation drawer. Any way Looks like you are using tranparent background for navigation drawer. Chnage opacity of your navigation drawer and

Comment: I don't find any problem with the xml.Any way i couldn't share it in comments section.It says too many comments!How can share?Did you notice my code.Setting is the only item that is using preferenceFragment,all other places it's fragment.See the code in the upper section,i'm calling preferenceFrgament inside the fragment.Is there any way to remove the prefrencefragment when drawer is open for another selection?

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and i resolved it by replacing 
***android.R.id.content*** 
to 
***R.id.container***.