# PreferenceFragment is over another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, preferences

I have app with Navigation Drawer. It consists of two items: Main and Settings. All items are Fragments. "Settings" extends PreferenceFragment.

I have problem. When I switch to PreferencesFragment and then later switch to MainFragment - PreferencesFragment not closed and is over MainFragment.

I have function showFragment() to switch fragments. One of the arguments this function is Fragment. But when I caused this function for PreferencesFragment I had error, because in this case argument is PreferencesFragment. After that I create function showFragmentPreferences().

It's work, but PreferencesFragment is not removed from the screen.

**MainActivity**

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListDrawer;
private HashMap<String, String> mapElements;

public static final String TAG_NAME = "TAG_NAME";
public static final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "TAG_FRAGMENT";

private String itemDrawerMain;
private String itemDrawerSettings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    itemDrawerMain = getString(R.string.item_drawer_main);
    itemDrawerSettings = getString(R.string.item_drawer_settings);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.draver_layout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_list);
    drawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    arrayListDrawer = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    AddMenuItem(mapElements, arrayListDrawer);

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String tag = arrayListDrawer.get(position).get(TAG_FRAGMENT);

            if (tag.equals(MainFragment.TAG_MAINFRAGMENT)) {
                showFragment(
                        MainFragment.newInstance(),
                        MainFragment.TAG_MAINFRAGMENT,
                        null,
                        true
                );
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }

            if (tag.equals(PreferencesFragment.TAG_PREFERENCE)) {
                showFragmentPreferences(
                        new PreferencesFragment(),
                        PreferencesFragment.TAG_PREFERENCE,
                        MainFragment.TAG_MAINFRAGMENT,
                        false
                );
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        }
    });

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
    );

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        showFragment(MainFragment.newInstance(), MainFragment.TAG_MAINFRAGMENT, null, true);
    }
}

private void AddMenuItem(HashMap<String, String> mapElements, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListDrawer) {
    mapElements = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapElements.put(TAG_NAME, itemDrawerMain);
    mapElements.put(TAG_FRAGMENT, MainFragment.TAG_MAINFRAGMENT);
    arrayListDrawer.add(mapElements);

    mapElements = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapElements.put(TAG_NAME, itemDrawerSettings);
    mapElements.put(TAG_FRAGMENT, PreferencesFragment.TAG_PREFERENCE);
    arrayListDrawer.add(mapElements);


    //дописать адаптер

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrayListDrawer, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

    drawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private void showFragmentPreferences(
        PreferencesFragment fragment,
        String tag,
        String clearToTag,
        boolean clearInclusive
) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (clearToTag != null || clearInclusive) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(
                clearToTag,
                clearInclusive ? FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE : 0
        );
    }
    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
}

//функция для переключения фрагментом
private void showFragment(
        Fragment fragment,
        String tag,
        String clearToTag,
        boolean clearInclusive
) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (clearToTag != null || clearInclusive) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(
                clearToTag,
                clearInclusive ? FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE : 0
        );
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

**PreferencesFragment**

```
public class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

public PreferencesFragment() {
}

public static final String TAG_PREFERENCE = "TAG_PREFERENCE";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

public static android.app.Fragment newInstanse() {
    return new PreferencesFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    return view;
}}
```

**MainFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public MainFragment() {
}

public static final String TAG_MAINFRAGMENT = "TAG_MAINFRAGMENT";

public static MainFragment newInstance() {
    return new MainFragment();
}

private Button btnGetResult;
private EditText editText;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    btnGetResult = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.main_fragment_btn);
    editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.main_fragment_edit_text);

    btnGetResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ResultActivity.class)
                            .putExtra(ResultActivity.EXTRA_EDIT_TEXT, editText.getText().toString())
            );
        }
    });

    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same thing as you, and I'm pretty sure that it's the problem regarding Fragment and support.v4.Fragment. You cannot mix support library and the other one. PreferenceFragment is not from the support library. Which `Fragment` does you `MainFragment` extend? (see the imports)

Comment: @Vucko. In MainFragment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; in PreferencesFragment: import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

Comment: This is the problem then. You must either use both fragments from the support library, OR both from app.Fragment. And use the same method for replacing them (otherwise they will be on top of each other)

Comment: Ok, I changed PreferencesFragment to support library and in function showFragment I call PreferencesFragment. On telephone PreferencesFragment not shown.

Comment: Well, if you're getting no error, then we're 1 step closer to the solution. That was the first step for sure. Post the xml of your PreferencesFragment.
Also use `PreferencesFragment.newInstance()` instead of `new PreferencesFragment()` when you're calling the `showFragment`

Comment: This issue can be resolved by following this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845105/how-to-create-preferencefragment-associated-with-a-sliding-drawer-in-android/39790782#39790782